# Simple graphics library / API for command-line linux (ArchLinux)?

Tags: c, linux, graphics, archlinux, low-level

I want to do some graphical stuff on ArchLinux. Nothing big, just some 2D lines, circles whatever. I actually like low-level coding, but I've seen the linux kernel does not provide any support for drawing graphics (like syscalls or whatever). So how do librarys like graphics.h work?

And, my next problem, how would you install that library on Arch linux? Because gcc tells me that graphics.h was not found on my computer. Can you install it or download the source from somewhere? Or is this a more complex task to do, because you can't draw graphics in command line mode or so? Do you need some additional drivers for the GPU?

Thank you for answers!

Comment: Nothing like this exist. Read aboy gtk, cairo, pango etc

Comment: I did this a while ago which allows you to plot points in a bmp. It has no dependencies and is free to use if you include the MIT license with whatever you use. https://github.com/FastAsChuff/Red-Julia-Set-Fractal-Generator. I also made it draw straight lines but haven't got round to uploading that yet. Let me know if you want that too...

Comment: SDL + basic OpenGL are very easy to setup.

Answer (score 1):

Arch is just a linux distro. There's no "Arch-specific" libraries; you can (and will have to use) one of the existing Linux-targetting libraries.

> So how do librarys like graphics.h work?

Not sure which `graphics.h` you're referring to. Looking into my /usr/include, there's multiple of these. But a single header will *never* be able to do calls into X or wayland, you really need to link dynamically for that.

So, they don't, whatever you think *what* does that.

> And, my next problem, how would you install that library on Arch linux? Because gcc tells me that graphics.h was not found on my computer.

It seems you found some text about *some* file called graphics.h somewhere and think it is what you need. It's not.

> but I've seen the linux kernel does not provide any support for drawing graphics (like syscalls or whatever)

Why would a kernel care about that? It's job is to offer a safe and compatible interface to hardware, not to do userland software tasks.

> Or is this a more complex task to do, because you can't draw graphics in command line mode or so?

This is Linux, not Windows 95 :) There's no such thing as "command line mode". What you *probably* mean is that you want to draw on a virtual terminal, but in general, that's a text thing. You can't draw on it.

There's *framebuffer console*, but that's not what you want either.

If you want to draw graphics, do it in your graphical environment (i.e., Wayland or X). And all these would usually do is, again, offer your software an API to actually put areas on the screen (Wayland really just offers your software a *surface* to draw on; X does that too, but also offers very bad drawing functions, which nobody uses anymore).

Because there's not one underlying standard how things are drawn and setting up things is cumbersome and error-prone, and different between X and Wayland, you need to use an actual *library* (not just some header file called graphics.h, wherever that came from), to paint something.

That's as low-level as it gets: your graphical system gives you something to draw on, you draw. You need to rely on your system to do that for you, because you can't know the hardware, graphics system, color modes, … you will be facing.

About the actual drawing:

Many choices. I recommend really thinking about whether you want to build graphics code in C – that becomes annoying and complex very quickly, and there's a reason why even large and very performance critical graphics engines move away from that.

If you really want as-low-level-as-it-gets without having to write your own abstractions for different systems that will cost much more time than writing your graphics application:

Sounds like a job for SDL. SDL comes with examples! Or you go for dearImgui, if you're more into building user interfaces that contain your drawings. There's many examples that come with the dearImgui source code, on Linux you probably want the OpenGL3 one, it's the easiest to work with (imho).

Regarding:

> And, my next problem, how would you install that library on Arch linux?

vs

> I actually like low-level coding

Hm, I think if you like C low-level coding, you will need a better understanding of what a *header* is, what a *library* is, what *linking* and *dynamic linking* are.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'm quite new to this and seems like I understand every concept yet. I know it's not a "command-line mode", but I meant the way the text is printed to the screen. I did some very basic OS Dev tutorial a while ago, and there, you can draw text or graphics to the screen using BIOS interrupts. But this interrupts are not availible in protected mode, so I wondered if the linux kernel offers something to manage this. I mean, somehow X or Wayland have to draw graphics, and I guess the thing I'm wondering about is how they do it.

Comment: And one question:
I'm running Arch in a VM, so is the video output that is shown in the VM window displayed by Arch or the kernel or whatever? Or is it just a serial text output that is rendered by my VM? I guess it's rendered by the OS, because you also have the choice to chane the font when installing arch (or later).

Comment: @axolotlKing0722 you are running gnome or something. It is like windows only for Linux. Learn about GTK and Cairo and you will be able to draw on the screen.

Comment: @axolotlKing0722 bios routines can't work on an operating system that controls the graphics card. What you read is, as I explained in my answer, absolutely not applicable to programming under Linux.

Comment: @axolotlKing0722 how they do it: layers and layers of abstraction. In the end, the kernel allows the graphical interface software to send drawing commands to the graphics card, or to simply fill pixel areas in GPU memory themselves. But how that is done depends completely on the hardware involved. That's why you need these layers of abstraction. Every computer is different, and it's your graphic stack's job to allow you to use that with one API that works for all. That's why you need something like SDL.